# Chkdsk F: /f Aborted after Data Recovered From BitLocker Using repair -bde

Tags: decryption, bitlocker

A partition on my drive was protected by BitLocker. It stopped opening all of a sudden showing me the error message "The disk structure is corrupted or unreadable".

I followed [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523219%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to recover the data (`repair-bde C: F: -rp *****...`) on an emptied portable hard disk. Recovery worked fine and I was asked to run `chkdsk F: /f` before opening the drive. chkdsk is giving me an error "Unable to determine volume version and state CHKDSK aborted".

When I try to open the F: drive, it says "media is corrupt".

I also [saw this thread on MS Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/the-type-of-file-system-is-ntfs-the-first-boot/5bb53e4a-bba2-451a-bab3-639a651bf891) but it is not helping.
In below image, I have recovered from H and destination was F, error also shown when I try to open F.

I will appreciate if someone can help as I seem to have lost very important data.

Comment: Missing image. And this is the wrong site for this question. If you fix the image issue, I'll migrate.

Comment: I am sorry for posting on a wrong place. Image is not necessary for the understanding. I cannot publish something which has more than 2 links. I will appreciate if you can migrate this to an appropriate place. Thank you!